# How can I get the whole number from an array/list of digits?

Tags: python

for example lets say you have
[5,6]
the output should be 56

the only method I can think of is to multiply each digit by its place value and then add it.
like this 5 x 10 + 6 x 1 = 56

Is there a simpler way of doing this? I guess I can convert to string, but I dont want to use string. Any other alternatives?

Comment: most of the solutions use some form of string conversion like .join.

Comment: Something like this `t = ''.join(str(x) for x in L)` then int(t)?  What's the definition of `simple way`?

Comment: some solution with less loops

Comment: @knight6231awz - to solve this it has to loop the list once.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def my_function(my_list):
    final = ""
    for i in my_list:
        final = final + str(i)
    return int(final)

integer = my_function([5, 6])  # My function will output 56
```

Comment: Please explain the steps (can use comments in code).

Answer (score -1):

I guess just multiplying corresponding digits by 1, 10, 100 etc. is the simplest. But you can do this in a cool way.

```
L = [4, 2, 0, 6, 9]
num = sum([10**(len(L)-i-1)*L[i] for i in range(len(L))])
```

Comment: "Cool way" means code that is short but neither easy to read, nor easy to understand. Can you explain the parts of this one-liner.